# Qt instant response to a pressed key from keybaord

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to move a stick to the left or to the right with arrow keys on the keyboard. This piece of code below can do it step by step, I mean, It does not matter whether i am holding the left arrow on the keyboard or i just clicked on it, the stick moves only 5 units. What i am trying to do is to move it as long as i hold the key.

```
bool handled = false;
if ( e->type() == QEvent::KeyPress )
{
    QKeyEvent *keyEvent = (QKeyEvent *)e;

    if ( keyEvent->key() == Qt::Key_Left )
    {
        left= (= == 0 ? -5 : 0);
        handled = true;
    }
    else if ( keyEvent->key() == Qt::Key_Right )
    {
        right= (right== 0 ? 5 : 0);
        handled = true;
    }
}
```

I could not find a method in QKeyEvent class that woudl work for what I want to do. How can I fix this?

Comment: Why do you do `right = (right == 0? 5: 0);`?, you could also explain that you are trying, not what you want and the problem you see in your writing, it is very confusing.

Comment: I think you can implement this by introducing a timer. Key press starts the timer and key release stops it. Handle timer's `timeout()` signal to move the stick left/right as many times as `timeout()` signal is emitted.

Comment: Can you please show what you do with the left and right variables after updating them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use a QAction ?
For instance, catching left key presses:

```
    QAction *action = new QAction("test", this);
    action->setShortcut(QKeySequence("Left"));

    this->addAction(action);

    this->connect(action, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(left_button_slot()));
```

And a slot

```
void Widget::left_button_slot()
{
    //do whatever you want
    QMessageBox::information(this, "Hey", "You pressed left key !");
}
```